# Ubunutu 17.10 - Skypeforlinux 18.14.76.4 - No Device found

Tags: usb, skype, display-resolution, webcam

SkypeForLinux does not allow me to use my webcam (Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920) even though Ubuntu does detect the webcam, which is confirmed by the command lsusb. The microphone inside the webcame works perfectly fine.

When I tried to use it in Cheese it didn't work as well, but after I changed the width and height inside the settings of Cheese to 1920 and 1080 respectively, it started to work.

I have a feeling that I have to change these values for skype as well, but I can not find a config file or anything. Does any one have any experience with this as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your skype version to 8.10 (uninstall your current version first) by downloading it from here: https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/.

I had the exact same problem you described with the exact same webcam and doing this fixed it.

Comment: Or update. This link help to find the most recent version (Aptitude has some latency).